# pthreads_cond_broadcast doesn't wake up all threads that are waiting

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I'm working on creating a multi-threaded file server. I've created a thread pool to handle requests from the client. Here is my code for the thread pool:

```
void *worker_call(void *thread_id){
    printf("Initialized thread #%ld \n", (long)thread_id);  

    //pull in initialized global configs
    extern pthread_mutex_t queue_m;
    extern pthread_cond_t worker_c;
    extern steque_t queue; 


    while(1){
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&queue_m) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while locking mutex in #%ld \n", (long)thread_id);
        }
            while(steque_isempty(&queue) == 1){
                printf("thread #%ld - Going to sleep...\n", (long) thread_id);
                pthread_cond_wait(&worker_c, &queue_m);
                printf("thread #%ld - I'm waking up...\n", (long) thread_id);
            }
            
            int *work = steque_pop(&queue);
            

        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue_m) != 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "An error occured while unlocking mutex in #%ld \n", (long)thread_id);
        }

        pthread_cond_broadcast(&worker_c);

        sleep(1); //added to make sure that the other threads have a chance to wake up

        printf("thread #%ld - what is the value of work: %d\n", (long) thread_id, *work);
        // process_request(&(work->ctx), work->path, work->arg, (long)thread_id);
        free(work);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

To test that my thread pool is starting correctly and all threads are taking on work, I created the following test:

```
int main(){
    int nthreads = 6;

    pthread_t threads[nthreads];
    long thread_ids[nthreads];

    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_attr_setscope(&thread_attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM);


    for(int t=0;t<nthreads;t++){
        thread_ids[t] = t;
        if( pthread_create(&threads[t],NULL, worker_call, (void *)thread_ids[t]) != 0 ) {
            printf("An error occured while creating thread: %d\n", t);
        }
    }

    pthread_attr_destroy(&thread_attr);

    //init multi-threading configs
    extern pthread_mutex_t queue_m;

    pthread_mutexattr_t m_attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&m_attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&m_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);

    pthread_mutex_init(&queue_m, NULL);

    extern pthread_cond_t worker_c;
    pthread_cond_init(&worker_c, NULL);

    extern steque_t queue; 

    steque_init(&queue);
    //create a simple queue with each item being an int. 
    //the goal is to simply remove the items from the queue.
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        
        int *work = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *work = i;
        steque_enqueue(&queue, work);
    }
    

    printf("queue size after creating it: %d\n", steque_size(&queue));

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&worker_c);

    for(int t=0;t<nthreads;t++){
        pthread_join(threads[t], NULL);
    }

    printf("All the threads finished processing\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Now this code runs successfully, however, only one thread wakes up and it does all the work as shown in the output below:

```
Initialized thread #0 
thread #0 - Going to sleep...
Initialized thread #1 
thread #1 - Going to sleep...
Initialized thread #2 
thread #2 - Going to sleep...
Initialized thread #3 
thread #3 - Going to sleep...
Initialized thread #4 
thread #4 - Going to sleep...
Initialized thread #5 
thread #5 - Going to sleep...
queue size after creating it: 5
thread #5 - I'm waking up...
thread #5 - what is the value of work: 0
thread #5 - what is the value of work: 1
thread #5 - what is the value of work: 2
thread #5 - what is the value of work: 3
thread #5 - what is the value of work: 4
thread #5 - Going to sleep...
```

My question is, why aren't the other threads waking up and grabbing items off of the queue? I've tried adding a delay of one second after issuing the pthread_cond_broadcast to give the other threads enough time to lock the mutex, but I have had no success with that method. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're accessing the shared state after unlocking the mutex that protects it. This probably isn't the main error but it's at least one of the errors.

Comment: Where specifically do you see that error?

Comment: Please share the `worker_call` code.

Comment: @user58967 The worker_call code is the first block of code above.

Comment: I think I was wrong - I misunderstood `work` as pointing to shared data.

Comment: Ah, yeah the queue is the only shared data in here. The idea is that we pop a work item off of the queue, then process the work item outside of the mutex. Thanks for looking though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your definition of success when you say "successfully running"? There are several race conditions here that are alarming and I'm surprised this is working at all. For instance, worker_call() is access the queue, mutex, and cond variables before they're actually initialized.

Also, when you initially push items into the queue in main(), you should wrap that code in a mutex because your threads are trying to access that variable as well.

My recommendation is that you fix those race conditions then update your results.

Additionally in worker_call, the worker is checking for queue emptiness before calling cond_wait but it doesn't check for emptiness after it wakes up. Since it's possible that there are fewer items than workers, that function will need to check for queue emptiness, again.

Comment: Wow that was it, I was using the mutex, cond variables prior to them being initialized. Thank you for the help! By "running successfully" I mean, when I ran this to transfer files - it worked. The files transfered. But not all the time. Occasionally it just broke. thanks so much!